# Iterate through list and append elements to struct

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to make program go through /proc/stat in elixir, just a simple exercise I've made for myself.

```
defmodule CpuUsage.Reader do
  use Task, CPUCore
  @path "/proc/stat"
  @cores 6

  @spec start_link(any) :: {:ok, pid}
  def start_link(_arg) do
    Task.start_link(&loop/0)
  end

  @spec loop :: no_return
  def loop() do
    File.stream!(@path)
    |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1, "\n", trim: true))
    |> Enum.slice(0, @cores)
    |> core_list = [ new_head | core_list] = [CPUCore.coresToStruct | _ ]
  end
end

defmodule CPUCore do
  defstruct [:number,
  :user   ,
  :nice   ,
  :system ,
  :idle   ,
  :iowait ,
  :irq     ,
  :softirq]

  @spec coresToStruct(any, any) :: none
  def coresToStruct([head | tail], iteration \\ 0) do
    key_list = [:number, :user, :system, :idle, :iowait, :irq, :softirq]
    core_list = [head | tail]
    coreStruct = %CPUCore{}
    String.split(head, " ", trim: true)
    |> Enum.reduce(key_list, fn(x, key_list, coreStruct) -> %CPUCore{key_list: x} end)
    if @cores - iteration > 2 do
      new_list = [core_list[1] | Enum.slice(core_list, 2, @cores - iteration)]
      coresToStruct(iteration + 1)
    end
  end

end
```

This is the code. The question is. I want to go through first line of the list I passed to coresToStruct. Then I want to do %CPUCore{number: first_string, user: second_string...etc}. How do I do that? Can't think of a proper solution :(

Comment: I'm not sure what this line is supposed to do `|> core_list = [ new_head | core_list] = [CPUCore.coresToStruct | _ ]`, but you can only pipe into functions. You probably mean `|> CPUCore.coresToStruct()` (and let `coresToStruct` pattern-match on the list), or `|> hd() |> CPUCore.coresToStruct()`?

Comment: There is a lot in your question not relevant to  "Iterate through list and append elements to struct". Please try to produce [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without all the /proc/stat stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question what you are trying to do, but here is an example of splitting a string, and using those values to populate a struct:

```elixir
defmodule MyStruct do
  defstruct [:a, :b, :c]

  def from_string(string) do
    [a, b, c | _] = String.split(string, " ")
    %MyStruct{a: a, b: b, c: c}
  end
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex> MyStruct.from_string("one two three")
%MyStruct{a: "one", b: "two", c: "three"}
```

Comment: `struct!(MyStruct, Enum.zip(~w[a b c]a, String.split(string))`